# Can Informatica be used on Windows system?

Tags: windows, windows-10, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I would like to know if Informatica can be used on Windows system ? If so what are the prerequisites?

Comment: I think you need to refer to informatica documentation. Infa supports Win 10 now. You can install server in win as well. Client as well can be installed into Windows. Tons of videos are there.

Comment: PowerCenter 9.x is not supported on Win10, but can be installed on it; 10.2 supports Win10. I believe most Windows Server OS will run the Suite w/out issues. Look online for the compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the previous answers are wrong.
Windows 10 is supported for installing the client tools only.

For exact details which Windows server versions are supported, please log on (after initial sign-up if you haven't already done so) to the Informatica Network at https://network.informatica.com ; there's a section named Product Availability Matrices, here you find for each PowerCenter version the so-called Product Availability Matrix (PAM) indicating which Windows versions are supported for server installation and for client installation. You need both, and you can install both on the same Windows server system.

I won't go into this ugly ancient flame war here. Be it enough to say that some people managed to install the server part on Windows 10, but very few ever made it work reliably (in most cases the installation seems to work but doesn't, at latest after the next system restart). I wouldn't waste one single second trying to do so, it's not worth the time.